# Where can I find Database Schema View for Database Project in VS2012 Final Release?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am looking for Database Schema View in VS2012 Final Release for my Database Project which was created in VS2010. In earlier version I was using SSDT and Power Tools. Is it required to used both these tools in VS2012 Final Release also. I am not able to find on Solution Explorer . Please assist me where can I find Schema View button to toggle my solutionview and schema view. I am using VS2012 Ultimate x64 edition on Windows 7 Ultimate

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned this feature is in the SSDT Power Tools, although VS2012 compatibility is yet to be introduced.

However according to Sam Hughes [MSFT], it shouldn't be too far away:

> Written August 23, 2012
>
> I am literally working on [SSDT power tools for VS2012] right now, but I'm not prepared to
>   publicly announce a date other than "soon".

Source:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b0228c6-15d1-44de-9279-66dde12bf861

Comment: Here is new SSDT PowerTools for VS2012 Download available http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/96a2f8cc-0c8b-47dd-93cd-1e8e9f34a917?SRC=Featured

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as that little gem is one of the things missing from SSDT.